# recurring event and non-recurring event using fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

```
events: [

     {
      id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
      title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
      color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
      start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
      end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
      dow: '<?php echo $dow; ?>',
      ranges: [{
                 start: '<?php echo $start; ?>', 
                 end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
               }]
      },
]
```

Following image below shows my current status of my calendar:
[image: Calendar]

As seen from the image above, the cardio training has been recurring non-stop. Is there a way to stop the recurring event based on the end date in ranges, other than using event render function?

**Take note:**
`<?php echo $start; ?>` and `<?php echo $end; ?>` is a date formatted in YYYY-MM-DD.

**UPDATED after attempting ADyson's solution:**
[image: updatedCalendar]

```
   <?php foreach ($events as $event): ..... ?> 
{
      id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
      title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
      color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
      start: '04:00',
      end: '05:00',
      dow: '<?php echo $dow; ?>',
      ranges: [{
                 start: '<?php echo $start; ?>', 
                 end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
               }]
}, 
{
      id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
      title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
      color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
      start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
      end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
} <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: data]

Apparently, it went into recurring and non-recurring event objects due to they are in the foreach loop.

**SOLUTION**

```
events:[
    <?php 
    inside the foreach loop:
    ..........
     if ($dow == "") {
        ?>
        {
          id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
          title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
          color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
          start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
          end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
        },
 <?php }
       else {?>
        {
          id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
          title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
          color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
          start: '04:00',
          end: '05:00',
          dow: '<?php echo $dow; ?>',
          ranges: [{
                     start: '<?php echo $start; ?>', 
                     end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                   }]
       },
   <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Try YYYY-MM-DD (- instead of /) to start with. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ which shows you the supported ISO formats for parsing dates (fullCalendar uses momentJS for this under the hood). Other than that there's no reason you can't do this. You also might want to modify the eventRender function a little to check whether `event.ranges` actually exists before trying to use it. Otherwise you'll get a JS error in the console

Comment: no, i do not have any JS error. I want to have recurring event and non-recurring event (which are those one day event) to appear in my calendar. However, i only can make one of them to appear in my calendar right now.

Comment: did you do what I suggested with the date format? And if you leave out the `ranges` property from an (otherwise acceptable) event object, you _will_ get a console error because ranges will be undefined - unless you also removed the eventRender code. But if you remove the eventRender code you also lose the ability to have other recurring events. Instead do what I suggested above - change the date format used in $start and $end, and alter eventRender so it checks whether event.ranges is defined before continuing.

Comment: my date format is actually in '-' instead of '/'. And i added what you suggested to check whether event.ranges is defined. The calendar only have recurring event displayed. I want those one day event which do not need to be recurred to be displayed in the calendar as well.

Comment: can you update the code in the question to show your current version, please. Then I can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: ADyson, i have re-updated my post. pls take a look. I removed my event render function so that one day event is able to display in my calendar. However, my recurring event (cardio training) is unable to stop at the end date. The cardio training event will always be recurring on monday and tuesday non-stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is perfectly possible. As I mentioned in the comments, all you have to do is modify the eventRender function to check whether the "ranges" property exists on the event being rendered. If it does, then apply the recurrence rules defined by the ranges. If not, then just allow it to render normally with no interference:

```
eventRender: function(event) {
  //only apply recurrence rules if the event has a "ranges" property
  if (event.ranges) {
    return (event.ranges.filter(function(range) { // test event against all the ranges

      return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
        event.end.isAfter(range.start));

    }).length) > 0; //if it isn't in one of the ranges, don't render it (by returning false)
  } else {
    return true; //just allow the event to render normally if it's not recurring
  }
}
```

For this to work, your events can have the following structures:

Non-recurring example:

```
{
  title: 'Non Recurring Event',
  start: "2017-10-03T10:30:00",
  end: "2017-10-03T11:30:00",
  allDay: false
}
```

Recurring example:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Recurring Event",
  start: "10:00",
  end: "12:00",
  dow: [1,3,4],
  ranges: [{
      start: "2017-10-01T09:30:00",
      end: "2017-10-04T15:30:00"
    }, {
      start: 2017-10-05T10:00:00",
      end: 2017-10-15T13:30:00"
    }]
}
```

See a working demo here, containing both recurring and non-recurring events: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/27/

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. But there is a slight issue now. As my non-recurring and recurring events are in a for loop. As such, my non-recurring event with a range of date also will get affected. I will be updating my post with the latest pic to show how it looks like now.

Comment: what do you mean by "in a for loop"? Where is this loop and what is its purpose? I'm guessing it's some code you use to generate the events. Without seeing it I can't give any particular advice, but I assume you have some sort of logical error which is adding ranges or other recurrence data (e.g. dow) to the non-recurring events when it shouldn't.

Comment: it is a foreach loop. it is inside the events object. Purpose is to retrieve from database.
`<?php
foreach ($events as $event):
.....
?>
{ 
with the recurring and non recurring example
}
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: you'd have to show me the exact code really. The problem is likely to be within the loop somewhere. But like I say, look for some code which accidentally adds dow and/or range properties to events which shouldn't have them. You can also look at the final event data output (in your page source in your browser, I would think) to confirm that this is what is happening.

Comment: It's immediately and clearly obvious from looking at the loop that it generates one non-recurring event, and one recurring event, for each $event from the database. You get one of each, every time. I assume that isn't what you want. Surely you need to use some info from $event to decide whether it is recurring or not? I can't begin to imagine how you thought that printing the event in both formats every time was going to work? I am a bit worried that do you not really understand on quite a basic level what your code is doing?

Comment: Ya. So inside the foreach loop, i actually did 
`$recur = $event['recur'];
// if no recur
    if ($recur == "") {
        $recur = "";
    }`
but with or without, it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: well why didn't you show that in your code that you gave to me before? And that code makes no sense anyway. What do you _do_ with this $recur value? Just blanking it out again, as per your snippet above, has no impact on anything at all. You need to use it to decide which bits of the event data to output. What can $recur actually contain? Is it a boolean (true/false), or a string? Or a number? What possible values are there? Once we know that, we can make an `if` statement to decide whether to add the recurrence properties or not.

Comment: its okay, it worked. I understand what im doing, okay. Is just that my logic is not strong enough, believe it or not up to u~~ Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it. But you do need to get stronger at the logic...it's pretty much the key to this whole programming thing :-)

Comment: I posted my solution ~ once again, thanks for the help

Comment: that's much better. Just one small thing, `$recur = "";` is completely redundant - you're doing it in the situation when recur already has this value. So this line does nothing useful, you can just remove it. And you don't need to repeat the code to define the id, title and color properties, since they are the same no matter what the value of recur is. You can define them (and the { } to start/end the JSON event) outside the if statement. This makes your code less repetitive, easier to understand, and easier to maintain (because a change to that bit then only needs to be done once).

Comment: thanks for pointing out. i tried to make it less repetitive, but it does not work. i think i did it in a wrong way. i tried to define the if statement inside the json then declare dow and ranges.